# Inner Zoom image when clicking on fancybox image gallery

Tags: php, jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com) for my web application

> Jquery

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
  openEffect    : 'none',
  closeEffect   : 'none',
  afterLoad :function() {
    this.title = 'Click to Enlarge';
  },
  afterShow :function() {
    $(".fancybox").zoom({on:"click"});
  }
});
```

> HTML

```
<script src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<link href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/313/19831416459_5ddd26103e_b.jpg" title="Sgwd Ddwli Uchaf, Brecon Waterfalls (technodean2000)">
    <img src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/313/19831416459_5ddd26103e_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5444/17679973232_568353a624_b.jpg" title="Golden Manarola (Sanjeev Deo)">
    <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5444/17679973232_568353a624_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7367/16426879675_e32ac817a8_b.jpg" title="Codirosso spazzacamino (Massimo Greco _Foligno)">
    <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7367/16426879675_e32ac817a8_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5612/15344856989_449794889d_b.jpg" title="Morning Twilight (Jose Hamra Images)">
    <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5612/15344856989_449794889d_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

I want to when open the fancy box image gallery after i click on center of image at the time if image are bigger than box then that zooming on inner of fancy-box and moving image on courser move.

Here on my code there is 4 images. if 2nd and 3rd image bigger than box then display title "Click to enlarge" and Zooming in on clicking only for 2nd and 3rd image not for 1st and 4th.

**Thanks in advance on your replay**

Answer (score 1):

You should do like

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
  openEffect    : 'none',
  closeEffect   : 'none',
  afterLoad :function() {
    this.title = 'Click to Enlarge';
  },
  afterShow :function() {
    //$(".fancybox").zoom({on:"click"});
  }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/313/19831416459_5ddd26103e_b.jpg" title="Sgwd Ddwli Uchaf, Brecon Waterfalls (technodean2000)">
    <img src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/313/19831416459_5ddd26103e_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5444/17679973232_568353a624_b.jpg" title="Golden Manarola (Sanjeev Deo)">
    <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5444/17679973232_568353a624_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7367/16426879675_e32ac817a8_b.jpg" title="Codirosso spazzacamino (Massimo Greco _Foligno)">
    <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7367/16426879675_e32ac817a8_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5612/15344856989_449794889d_b.jpg" title="Morning Twilight (Jose Hamra Images)">
    <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5612/15344856989_449794889d_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

Comment: i want inner zoom after fancybox open and click on open image.

Comment: I mean inside zooming in fancybox onclick anywhere on fancybox and moving on cursor.